# Mean kinetic energy without full laplacian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction

I need to calculate by solving the integrals the expectation value of the kinetic energy $\hat{T}$ and potential energy $\hat{V}$ operators in the state $\Psi$, defined as
$$
\Psi(r) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi}} a_0^{-3} e^{-r/a_0}\,,
$$
$$
\hat{T} = - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m_e}\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} + \frac2{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)\,,\qquad
\hat{V}=-\frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0r}\,.
$$

When doing the integral, no matter how I try to do things, I keep getting an $r$ in the denominator because of the $2/r$. Since I integrate from zero to infinity the answer is undefined.

Comment: Hi, welcome to physics.SE. I did a major reshaping of your post because we prefer formulas to be typeset within the question and not with pictures. Moreover have a look at the policy for asking homework-related questions [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/196314). We prefer that you show us what you got so far and which steps got you stuck.

Comment: Have you tried to solve it in momentum space, instead of position space? Of course you have to calculate psi in momentum space as well by Fourier transform

Answer (score 2):

Are you putting the $r^2$ into the integration measure?
$$
\langle E\rangle = 4\pi \int \psi^*(r) (\hat T+\hat V)\psi(r) r^2 dr.
$$
This does not look divergent to me.

Notice that the $\hat T$ operator is that for three-dimensional space, where 
$$
\hat T = -\hbar^2\left(\frac {\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac {\partial^2}{\partial y^2}+\frac {\partial^2}{\partial z^2}\right)\\
=-\hbar^2 \left( \frac {\partial^2}{\partial r^2}+\frac 2 r \frac {\partial}{\partial r}+\frac 1 {r^2}\left(\frac 1{\sin\theta} \frac {\partial}{\partial \theta}\sin \theta \frac {\partial}{\partial \theta}+ \frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}\frac {\partial^2}{\partial \phi^2}\right)\right)
$$
when expressed in spherical polar coordinates. For spherically symmetric functions like your $\Psi(r)$ only the $r$ derivatives matter, and we have
$$
\langle \psi\vert \hat H\vert \chi\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi^*(x,y,z)\hat H \chi(x,y,z) dxdydz \\= 4\pi \int_0^\infty \psi^*(r) (\hat T+\hat V)\chi(r) r^2dr
$$

Comment: No i was using the expectation value integrals, the ones with just the complex variant of the wavefunction times the operated wavefunction (with just one operator, basicly trying to do one expectation value at a time for each operator). I dont understand why that would not work and why i instead have to use the equation you used?

Comment: @Daneil S. It is the three-dimensional kinetic energy opertaor, so you are supposed to use the three-dimensional integrals. I'll add an extra line in my answer to explain this.